# How to get the other devices' host name in the same wifi?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, wifi

I found some iOS app which could scan the local network and list all the device information.

I wonder how.

Pic:[image]

Comment: This uses Bonjour, Apple's implementation of MDNS, formerly known as ZeroConf.

Comment: Are you able to fetch the hostname ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Step 1 - Gel local IP

For iOS 7 and lower

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

- (NSString *)getIPAddress {

    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;
    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL) {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];

                }

            }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;

}
```

iOS 8

```
[[NSHost currentHost] address]
```

## Step 2 - Get online IPs

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability
Using Reachability, you can get subnet IP's reachability.

```
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:subnetIp];
```

## Step 3 - Resolve hostname

Apple has a great article, which covers HostnameResolving topics.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/ResolvingDNSHostnames.html

You can try also simpler variant in iOS8

```
[[NSHost hostWithAddress:@"173.194.34.24"] name]
```

## Example project

https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan
here is a small project, that does the Local Area Network scan, you need only to resolve the hostnames, and you will get result that you want.

Comment: Is NSHost now available for public use on iOS 8? I would be THRILLED if it is, but I'm not finding it in the docs or Foundation headers…

Comment: is [[NSHost hostWithAddress:@"your_ip_address"]  name] available for iPhone applications? If yes then how can I use that?

Comment: NSHost only available for OsX

Comment: How to fetch hostname in iOS ?