# List device's names in the local network

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, network-programming, netbios

I'm able to fetch connected devices IP and their MAC address and also would like to fetch the device's names and services(open ports).

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: I know that this post is too much old, but can you help me out for fetching the devices IP and their MAC address.?

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample project that can be helpful [An iOS Local Area Network / wifi Scanner](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan)

Also u can try to use [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)

And here - [even more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25993182/2012219) regarding name of device in lan

---

I Found few variants:

1.

```
struct hostent *he;
struct in_addr ipv4addr;
inet_pton(AF_INET, [address UTF8String], &ipv4addr);
he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof ipv4addr, AF_INET);
if (he) {
    printf("Host name: %s\n", he->h_name);
}
```

where [address UTF8String] - like 127.0.0.1 (ip)

2.

```
- (NSArray *)hostnamesForAddress:(NSString *)address {
    // Get the host reference for the given address.
    struct addrinfo      hints;
    struct addrinfo      *result = NULL;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family   = PF_UNSPEC; /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    int errorStatus = getaddrinfo([address cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (errorStatus != 0) return @[[self getErrorDescription:errorStatus]];

    CFDataRef addressRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if (addressRef == nil) return nil;

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, addressRef);
    if (hostRef == nil) return nil;
    CFRelease(addressRef);
    BOOL isSuccess = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, NULL);
    if (!isSuccess) return nil;

    // Get the hostnames for the host reference.
    CFArrayRef hostnamesRef = CFHostGetNames(hostRef, NULL);
    NSMutableArray *hostnames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < [(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef count]; currentIndex++) {
        [hostnames addObject:[(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
    }

    return hostnames;
}

- (NSString *)getErrorDescription:(NSInteger)errorCode
{
    NSString *errorDescription = @"";;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case EAI_ADDRFAMILY: {
            errorDescription = @" address family for hostname not supported";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_AGAIN: {
            errorDescription = @" temporary failure in name resolution";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_BADFLAGS: {
            errorDescription = @" invalid value for ai_flags";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_FAIL: {
            errorDescription = @" non-recoverable failure in name resolution";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_FAMILY: {
            errorDescription = @" ai_family not supported";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_MEMORY: {
            errorDescription = @" memory allocation failure";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_NODATA: {
            errorDescription = @" no address associated with hostname";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_NONAME: {
            errorDescription = @" hostname nor servname provided, or not known";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_SERVICE: {
            errorDescription = @" servname not supported for ai_socktype";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_SOCKTYPE: {
            errorDescription = @" ai_socktype not supported";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_SYSTEM: {
            errorDescription = @" system error returned in errno";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_BADHINTS: {
            errorDescription = @" invalid value for hints";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_PROTOCOL: {
            errorDescription = @" resolved protocol is unknown";
            break;
        }
        case EAI_OVERFLOW: {
            errorDescription = @" argument buffer overflow";
            break;
        }
    }
    return errorDescription;
}
```

  3.

Additional info u can get from `getifaddrs(&interfaces)` where `struct ifaddrs* interfaces` like

```
    unsigned char *ptr;
    ptr = (unsigned char *)LLADDR((struct sockaddr_dl *)(temp_addr)->ifa_addr);

    NSString *ip = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
    NSArray *hostsNames = [self hostnamesForAddress:ip];
    NSMutableDictionary *info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                                     @{
                                       @"name": @(temp_addr->ifa_name),
                                       @"flags": @(temp_addr->ifa_flags),
                                       @"ip" : ip,
                                       @"family": @(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family),
                                       @"mac" :  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MAC[%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x]", *ptr, *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3), *(ptr+4), *(ptr+5)],
                                       @"hostName" : hostsNames.count ? hostsNames : @""
                                       }
                                     ];
```

As result u will get something like:

```
{
    family = 2;
    flags = 32841;
    hostName =     (
        localhost
    );
    ip = "127.0.0.1";
    mac = "MAC[00:00:00:00:00:00]";
    name = lo0;
}
{
    family = 18;
    flags = 34915;
    hostName = ""; //here empty due to one of the following problem or due to CFHostStartInfoResolution return NO - o this point required a little bit more works to be done
    ip = "6.3.6.0";
    mac = "MAC[02:00:00:00:00:00]";
    name = en1;
}
```

Also [this post very interesting](http://blog.toshsoft.de/index.php?/archives/5-3-Ways-to-Resolve-a-Hostname-in-iOS.html) and may be useful (I will investigate it later)

Some info that can be helpful regarding `ifa_name`  (interfaces)

```
    //            pdp_ip -  interfaces are those that are used for 3G and cellular data
    //            lo = localhost
    //            en = ether
    //            eth - ethernet
    //            wlan, ww, wl - Wifi - Wireless LAN
    //            awdl - ???
    //            utun - ???
    //            ap - is used to represent currently active data connection, Wi-Fi, cellular data or bluetooth or for access point
    //            bridge - Active hotSpot connection
    //            sl -- serial line IP (slip)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with "wifi scanner" I am able to get device ip and mac but not device name. With "Bonjour" I am unable to get non apple devices information.

Comment: this is like a start point u can go more deeply with code provided by author of wifiScanner and investigate - u can fetch name of device from struct that holds mac ip etc. As i mentionted - this is start point. Also see my update

Comment: Hey @Kirill, I could not able to get device name from "wifiScanner", I have gone through the code and found below struct and tried for the possibilities. 

struct addrinfo {
 int ai_flags; /* AI_PASSIVE, AI_CANONNAME, AI_NUMERICHOST */
 int ai_family; /* PF_xxx */
 int ai_socktype; /* SOCK_xxx */
 int ai_protocol; /* 0 or IPPROTO_xxx for IPv4 and IPv6 */
 socklen_t ai_addrlen; /* length of ai_addr */
 char *ai_canonname; /* canonical name for hostname */
 struct sockaddr *ai_addr; /* binary address */
 struct addrinfo *ai_next;
};

could you please provide any snippet (bonjour or any)

Comment: thanks @kirill for your efforts, I have tried all the solutions that you have given but no luck and I have been trying with bonjour, with that able to get the names of desktops and laptops but not mobiles and other devices.